# how to stop image size change when thumbnails on and off

Tags: android

I have image viewer in a viewpager with thumbnails.I added thumbnails as horizontal scroll viewer which is visible for single click and hide if click again.The issue is when the thumbs are hiding the image size is increasing.again image is visible image size is decreasing.So how to stop this image resizing os is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Just set them static width and height in dimens res. I think this is the easiest way to resolve this problem.